# how to understand image topic frame orientation?

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, tf2, camera-info, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

as the title says, I want to ask how to figure out how the frame orientation of an image is set, any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382254/how-to-understand-image-topic-frame-orientation?/) by [Ifx13](https://answers.ros.org/users/70606/ifx13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2021-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Documentation of the orientation of an image message can be found in the message itself with Z forward:

http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html

It usually uses the `_optical` postfix for the frame_id to be clear that it's different than the standard coordinate frames with X forward. https://ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2